# Kendo UI > Update Grid > Internal Server Error Generated

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, kendo-ui

I've been beating my head against my desk for a few days now… time I asked for help.

I'm trying to update a value within Kendo UI's grid. The grid displays correctly, as does the popup editor. That's where the good times end. Here's the situation:

1. Click 'Edit' > Popup Opens > Click 'Update' (no change made) > Popup closes. Result = As expected.
2. Click 'Edit' > Popup Opens > Click 'Cancel' > Popup closes. Result = As expected.
3. Click 'Edit' > Popup Opens > Update the 'clientName' field > Click 'Update'. Result = Value in the row changes (in the background), popup stays open and a alert is displayed stating 'undefined'. If I then close the popup the change is lost. As part of this process a 500 internal server error is also generated.

Here's my Kendo code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "assets/data/",
                        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read:  {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "data.clients.php",
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "data.clients.update.php",
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "data.clients.create.php",
                                },

                                parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            batch: true,
                            pageSize: 10,
                            error: function(e) {
                                alert(e.responseText);
                            },
                            schema: {
                                data: function(result) {     
                                  return result.data || result;
                                },
                                total: function(result) {
                                    var data = this.data(result);
                                    return data ? data.length : 0;
                                },
                                model: {
                                    id: "clientID",
                                    fields: {
                                        clientID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        clientName: { validation: { required: true } },
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        pageable: true,
                        toolbar: ["create"],
                        columns: [
                            { field: "clientID", title: "Client ID" },
                            { field: "clientName", title: "Client Name"},
                            { command: "edit", title: "&nbsp;", width: 110 }],
                        editable: "popup"
                    });
                });
```

Here's my PHP:

```
include '../includes/connect.php';

    $clientName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["clientName"]);
    $clientID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["clientID"]);

    $rs = mysql_query("UPDATE cms_clients SET clientName = '" .$clientName ."' WHERE clientID = " .$clientID);

    if ($rs) {
        echo json_encode($rs);
    }
    else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
        echo "Update failed for EmployeeID: " .$clientID;
    }
```

Oh, and I know this code has issues with potential injection. That's step 2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
@rrfive